# Is it possible to "sleep" while aware and cognizant?

Tags: sleep, neurology

I have a scenario, but before I begin, I would like to clarify that this is not Sleep Paralysis, nor Lucid Dreaming, nor what I understand a Trance to be.

Let's say that someone decided they needed to take a nap, because they were exhausted and sleep-deprived. However, instead of sleeping normally, they sort-of transitioned into a strange state of consciousness which I will try to describe below.

- The muscles felt tight, but not unpleasantly so. They could feel where the muscles had been tight up to two hours after the experience, but it was not sore.
- They were conscious and thinking, but emotions and opinions didn't seem to move as fast, and didn't feel like they had as much weight. They felt really relaxed.
- They **could** move. They could prove this by experimenting with shifting their feet and hands. Small movements like these did not break this state, but larger movements would temporarily make them feel fully awake again, until they became still and eventually settled back into this altered state.
- They remember the experience vividly, unlike when they have a dream or even a lucid dream.
- Nothing super weird happened, and the experience was the same each time they drifted into this state.
- Unlike during Sleep Paralysis, the limbs did not feel like dead weight. They felt tight, and like some sort of atmospheric pressure (again, not an uncomfortable level) was being exerted all over the body, but the feeling was significantly different from the cold, dead feeling of Sleep Paralysis.
- They were aware that they were breathing, though it felt shallow even though they knew it wasn't.
- They felt more rested after that experience than they normally do after a full sleep cycle.

#### My question is, what exactly *would* this be, and where do I go to find-out more about it?

Comment: Personal medical advice is off topic here.

Comment: I'm looking to research this. It's not medical advice I'm seeking, it's what this is, and where I go to research further.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can edit your question to make it generic and not about **you** and **your** experiences, and turn it into a question about how to research this further that will be helpful to others, but I'm just not finding a way. Can you make it not about you? Please do if you can.

Comment: @CareyGregory I will try. I'm really tired right now, so I'll have to do it tomorrow.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath - I edited your question for you a while ago after CareyGregory made a comment.  Hopefully this fits the bill for you